# When I am trying to add network images in my flutter application it shows invalid image data. How can I resolve this?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 Positioned(bottom: -70,
            left: 10,
            child: Container(
                width: 350,
                height: 450,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Image.network("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Manchester_City_FC_badge.svg"))
```

I am getting a result "invalid image data".

Answer (score 0):

that is because flutter's `Image.network` does not handle `svg` data type. try using [flutter_svg package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) instead.

Comment: Instead of providing a link as an answer, you could comment, else provide the whole implementation of [SVG](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) with [network](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg/example)

Comment: I don't see how is it necessary to copy part of the documentation, as they will have to navigate to the link to copy the installation script anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred due to using svg image in image widget,image widget doesn't support svg so you need to use another package to use svg image.

**PS:** After downloading the package uninstall the app and run flutter clean and run pub get

**Download**

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

**Example code**

use this instead of image widget

With Network image

```
SvgPicture.network(
  'https://site-that-takes-a-while.com/image.svg',
  semanticsLabel: 'A shark?!',
  placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
);
```

With Asset image

```
final String assetName = 'assets/up_arrow.svg';
final Widget svgIcon = SvgPicture.asset(
  assetName,
  color: Colors.red,
  semanticsLabel: 'A red up arrow'
);
```